# Complex Number Problem: Find the Cartesian equation for point $P (x,y)$ if $z=x+iy$

Tags: complex-numbers

Can anyone help me with a complex number problem please?

Find the Cartesian equation for the locus of points $P(x, y)$ if $z = x + iy$ and: $|z+3|+|z-3|=8$. I tried four different situations such as when $$(z+3) \geq 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad (z-3) \geq 0,$$ 
when $$(z+3) \leq 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad (z-3) \leq 0,$$
when $$(z+3) \geq 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad (z-3) \leq 0,$$
and when $$(z+3) \leq 0 \qquad\text{and}\qquad (z-3) \geq 0.$$
I got $x=4 $ and $x=-4$. I do not know how to proceed at this point and the answer given to this question is $7x^2+16y^2=112$.

Comment: What means IB HL?

Comment: Hello: I would encourage you to think a little about "how to ask for help" vs "asking people to do something for me."  Perhaps you really do want the first, but in effect you have asked for the second.  You could achieve the first one better by meeting us halfway and including your efforts and thoughts about the problem.

Comment: @miracle173, IB HL (International Baccalaureate) which is the diploma that I am currently studying. This problem is from my higher level math textbook.

Comment: @rschwieb Thank you for your suggestion! I have edited the problem already:)

Comment: @QinkeLyu OK, I can tell you that this is much improved. If you do the same next time, it will probably prevent down and close votes entirely!  I retracted the negative votes I originally gave this question.

Answer (score 2):

In the complex numbers $|z-3|$ doesn't split into the cases $z-3\ge0$ and $z-3<0$. There's no order relation on the complex numbers (compatible with the operations).

Hint: the sum of the distances with two fixed points is constant. Does it ring a bell?

Otherwise, write the equation as $|z-3|=8-|z+3|$ and square, recalling that $|w|^2=w\bar{w}$ (the overline meaning conjugation).

Note that $|z-3|^2=(z-3)(\bar{z}-3)=z\bar{z}-3z-3\bar{z}+9$ and similarly for $|z+3|^2$. Observe also that, for $z=x+yi$, $z+\bar{z}=2x$. It should be easier, now.

Comment: I get the value of Z but I still don't know how to convert that into the cartesian equation.

Comment: @QinkeLyu I'm not sure what you mean by “get the value of $z$”. I added some more hints.